# How to encrypt a JSON field and then read that field back into the JSON

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I am able to retrieve a field that I want to encrypt from a column containing a JSON object, once I encrypted this field I would like to read it back into the JSON. So this is how my dataframe looks:

```
json: struct
 id:string
 pii:string
 type:string
 dataContentType:string
 dataSchema:string
 time:string
enqueuedTime:date
```

Two columns (JSON, EnqueuedTime) so I want to be able to grab pii value and encrypt this and then read this back into the JSON column. We have a current solution that flattens the JSON into separate columns but the client would like to keep the original JSON structure. I am struggling to find a way to read the encrypted value back into the JSON or to reverse the flattening of the JSON via PySpark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This minimal self-contained example shows you how to encrypt your `pii` field with `withColumn`, `withField` and a custom udf function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

structureSchema = T.StructType([
          T.StructField('json', T.StructType([
             T.StructField('id', T.StringType(), True),
             T.StructField('pii', T.StringType(), True),
             ])),
         ])

df = spark.createDataFrame([(("123", "some json"),), (("456", "some more json"),)], structureSchema)
df.show()

@udf(returnType=T.StringType()) 
def encrypt_json(s):
  return "Enc: " + s

df_result = df.withColumn("json", F.col("json").withField("pii", encrypt_json(F.col("json.pii"))))
df_result.show()
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+
|                json|
+--------------------+
|    {123, some json}|
|{456, some more j...|
+--------------------+

+--------------------+
|                json|
+--------------------+
|{123, Enc: some j...|
|{456, Enc: some m...|
+--------------------+
```

You of course need to substitute the `encrypt_json` udf function with your own encryption function.